# Resolve split string in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I have two tables in a Microsoft SQL Database, one contains 3 columns with separated values (by comma and/or slash, but both should be equally treated as a separator).
Then I have another Table that contains an ID which is the same as each item in the split string from TABLE1.
I want to resolve the items in TABLE 1 so the Text from the matching row in TABLE2 is displayed. 
Is there a way to achieve this?

TABLE1

```
Text1           Text2           Text3
TA12,TA250      T1  
TA12,TA250      T1  
TA12,TA250      TA250,TA12      T310/T52
TA12,TA250      TA250           T310/T52
```

TABLE2

```
TA12            Hello
TA250           World
T1              This is a Test
T310            You are
T52             a Hero
```

Desired Result

```
Text1           Text2           Text3
Hello World     This is a Test  NULL
Hello World     This is a Test  NULL
Hello World     World Hello     You are a Hero
Hello World     World           You are a Hero
```

I'm able to achieve this using C#, but i would very much prefer this to happen on the SQL side.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Also, string manipulation is highly vendor specific. We need to know the rdbms and version you are working with to have a chance to answer this question.

Comment: @jarlh I of course would never ever do this, but this is an existing database ;) Believe me, I could yell at the guys who made this.. :(

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's Microsoft SQL, sorry for that...

Comment: Which version? Newer versions have a `split()` function that would be helpful

Comment: If it's Micosoft SQL Server 2016 or later, *and* the database is `compatibility_level = 130` or better, the you can use [STRING_SPLIT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) ... but SQL is really bad at string manipulation. You may prefer to do this on the C# client side.

Comment: What you do is first split the strings in Table1, then use a join with Table2 to get the translations for each individual item, and then aggregate the translation results for each column. You need to make sure you aggregate the translations in the exact same order as the original string is otherwise your result might get a Yoda effect: `a Hero You are` instead of `You are a Hero`.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 :)

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks, that's what I'd like to achieve, but as AlwaysLearning mentioned, it's perhaps easier if i do this with C# :/

Comment: Well, the correct things to do is to fix the database structure - however I know that sometimes that is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the most recent version of SQL Server, you can do:

```
select t.*, t1.new_text1, t2.new_text2, t3.new_text3
from table1 t outer apply
     (select string_agg(t2.col2) as new_text1
      from table2 t2
      where t2.col1 in (select * from string_split(replace(t.text1, '/', ','), ','))
     ) t1 outer apply
     (select string_agg(t2.col2) as new_text2
      from table2 t2
      where t2.col1 in (select * from string_split(replace(t.text2, '/', ','), ','))
     ) t2 outer apply
     (select string_agg(t2.col2) as new_text3
      from table2 t2
      where t2.col1 in (select * from string_split(replace(1.text3, '/', ','), ','))
     ) t3;
```

That said, fixing your data model should take precedence over trying to use it.

Comment: That will work, but it might yield results in the wrong order, though.. string_split does not keep the order of the original items.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, this works, thank you very much! It will actually be used to transfer all the existing Data from an old Database to an entirely new and normalized Database, and certainly we are no longer putting any arrays in a single cell :) Thank you all very much for you help!